# How do you support both doubles and long doubles without changing format specifiers?

Tags: c, floating-point, printf, double, format-string

I was able to compile [xnec2c](https://www.xnec2c.org/) with `long double`'s by simply search-replacing `double` with `long double`.  It calculates correctly, except anywhere that a format specifier is used because it wants `%Lf`... and of course GCC is barking quite a bit about `-Wformat=` after hacking it in with this one-liner:

```bash
perl -p -i -e 's/_Complex/complex/g; s/gdouble/double/g; s/([ \t(]|^)double/$1long double/g' src/*.[ch]
```

Ultimately the goal is to:

1. Replaces all `double`'s with `typedef double xnec2c_double_t`
2. Provide a `./configure --enable-long-double` option in `configure.ac` that adjusts the typedef to `long double`.
3. Not break `printf`'s and related format specifier-based functions (like `sprintf`, etc).

**Question:**

What are the best practices for making format specifiers work with compile-time selection of `double` vs `long double` by changing the `typedef`?

I could go put `#ifdef`'s around every print, or `#define SPEC_DOUBLE "%Lf"` and string-concatenate as `printf("foo=" SPEC_DOUBLE "\n", foo)` but that seems almost as hackish as adding `#ifdef`'s around every `printf`.  A `my_smart_printf` macro could be an option if there is an elegant way to do it, but I've not come up with one.

Is there a "good" way to do this?

Nota bene:

- I'd rather not switch to C++.
- This question is not about autoconf.
- I am the xnec2c maintainer.

Comment: Use `L` and a cast: `printf("%Lf\n", (long double) double_or_long_double_object);`

Comment: Personally, I like your `#define SPEC_DOUBLE "%Lf"` approach.  What is so bad about that?  Although to match `PRI` macros, it should be `#define SPEC_DOUBLE "Lf"`.

Comment: I second the views of @chux-ReinstateMonica: I'd create a typedef for the type and make the definition of that type a compile-time choice.  I'd also create a set of macro names for `scanf()` and `printf()` formats based on the scheme used in `<inttypes.h>`.  The standard reserves PRI or SCN followed by a lower-case letter or X for future use.  If you have a standard project prefix (I'll assume it is PFX), then I'd use names like `PFX_PRIG_typedefname`and `PFX_SCNf_typedefname` (where the `typedefname` is the name you invented for your typedefs, minus any project prefix). _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ If you don't have a project prefix and don't want to invent one, then using `PRI_G_typedefname` is close to what the standard uses for integers but not in the reserved namespace.  You might then have `#define PFX_PRIG_typedefname "LG"` for the `long double` code, and `#define PFX_SCNf_typedefname "lf"` for the regular `double` code.  And I'd exploit the symmetry of `printf()` and `scanf()` w.r.t `"%lf"` working for `double` in both, even though `printf()` would be happy with `"%f"` for `double`.

Comment: `SPEC_DOUBLE` is what I use, personally, in such situations. But, I also do: `printf("%s\n",print_double(whatever));` with: `const char *print_double(double val) { static char buf[100]; sprintf(buf,"%f",val); return buf; }` and adjust it for `long double` if needed, using macros like `SPEC_DOUBLE` instead of `%f` and (e.g.) `typedef long double TYPE_DOUBLE;` or `#define TYPE_DOUBLE long double` instead of `double`. Then only the function has to vary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do you support both doubles and long doubles without changing format specifiers in C?

- Convert the floating point argument to `long double` and use matching `long double` specifiers so the same format can be used in all cases.

  ```
  printf("%Lf\n", (long double) float_or_double_or_long_double_object);
  ```
- Follow the `PRI...` example from `<inttypes.h>` and create your own specifier as in `#define SPEC_DOUBLE "Lf"`.  Note no `"%"`.

  ```
  printf("%" SPEC_DOUBLE "\n", xnec2c_double_object);
  ```
- Create a helper function to convert your special floating point into a *string*.

  ```
  extern char *xnec2c_to_str(char *dest, xnec2c_double_t x);
  //                     -        digits           .  frac  \0 
  #define xnec2c_STR_SZ (1 + (LDBL_MAX_10_EXP+1) + 1 + 6 + 1)
  #define xnec2c_TO_STR(x) (xnec2c_to_str((char[xnec2c_STR_SZ]){ 0 }, x)
  printf("%s\n", xnec2c_TO_STR(x));
  ```
- [And now for something completely different](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0hYZaqYCZyQ), consider [Formatted print without the need to specify type matching specifiers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/115143/29485).